# PHP uses a PHP.ini file that does not exist

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

I need to upgrade my PHP version in WordPress, but when I try, it still returns me the older version, even the folder does not exist.

[image: Wrong path]

[image: Actual Path in server]

Comment: Well, did you adjust the php configuration inside the http server to match the newly installed php installation?

Comment: May I know which OS u r using?

Comment: @dspillai I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: @arkascha being sincerely, I've no idea how to adjust this, i've checked for some info in apache.conf about php version, but i've found nothing

Comment: First you have to check installed php versions. Open the terminal and enter sudo update-alternatives --list php. If your version in available first enmode it. Before you have to dismod the current version. sudo a2dismod php<current version> sudo a2enmod php<desired version> systemctl restart apache2

Comment: @dspillai 5.6, 7.2, 7.4 and 8.1, unfortunately I can't remove the 7.2 right now

Comment: I've done the  a2dismod and a2enmod before, I've tried i another server and works well, but in this it's kinda stuck

Comment: please open you phpinfo.php file. Can you check which version is currently using?

Comment: The shown path points to the fpm variant of php. Not to the one for the apache module. So which one do you want to operate?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and do not use images in questions (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps for updating :

1. Add PPA repository for PHP

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

2. Update Ubuntu

Open terminal and run the following commands to update Ubuntu packages.

`sudo apt-get update`

3. Install PHP (Whichever version you wanna install like 7.4 8 etc)

`sudo apt install php7.4`

```
Check php version
```

`sudo php -v`

4. Install PHP Extensions (Optional)

PHP extensions are commonly used along with PHP. Install them with the following command.

`sudo apt install php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-imagick php7.4-cli php7.4-dev php7.4-imap php7.4-mbstring php7.4-opcache php7.4-soap php7.4-zip php7.4-intl -y`

5. Enable PHP 7.4 for Apache

Next you need to disable your old PHP (say 7.0) and enable new PHP 7.4.

`sudo a2dismod php7.0`
 `sudo a2enmod php7.4`

6. Restart Apache Server

Restart Apache web server to apply changes

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Now i'm getting an error after restart apache service, even when I try to return to the old php a2enmod